# Navbar elements won't take on same line-height

Tags: css, html-lists, navbar

I have this navbar in html:

```
<div class="navbar">
            <p class ="logo">Vris</p>
            <ul class="navitems">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

And the following css to go along with it:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    background: #181818;
    height: 3.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.navitems {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3em;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
}

li {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 2em;
    float: left;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
```

But the UL and

elements in the navbar won't take on the same line-height. Why? I set the line-height in the parent navbar class, so the

and  children should inherit it, right?

Comment: Line-height is proportional to font-size and you're changing that on the `li`. It's not clear what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center vertically you need to use the same line-height as it is in height.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    background: #181818;
    height: 3.5em;
    line-height: 3.5em;
}

.navitems {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3em;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
}

li {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 2em;
    float: left;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
            <p class ="logo">Vris</p>
            <ul class="navitems">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` is one of those weird things that doesn't nest... put the `line-height` on the li.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/justicart/pen/goJdBx